# How can I optimize simple socket communication?

Tags: java, performance, sockets, network-protocols

Client sends a message. Server reads the message and writes a reply. Client reads the reply. Repeat. Each message is shorter than 500 bytes. Sockets are not closed.

I get around 800 request+responses/per second between two desktop PCs on LAN. Network activity on the hosts are barely noticeable.

If I don't do `readReply` (or do it in a separate thread), throughout explodes to like 30.000 msg/sec or more! This also peaks the network activity on the hosts.

My questions:

1. *Is 800 msg/sec a reasonable number for a request/response protocol on a single socket?*
2. *How is it that removing the readReply call can increase performance like that???*
3. *What can be done to improve this, apart from using UDP?* Any other protocol that might be used?

Server:

```
while (true) {
   message = readMessage();
   writeReply("Thanks");
}
```

Client:

```
while (true) {
   writeMessage("A message");
   reply = readReply();
}
```

Notes:

- I implemented this in both Java and Php and got about the same results.
- Ping latency is <1 ms

Comment: One suggestion - blocking wait on a socket.  If the readReply() has to wait for the other side to "wakeup -stop blocking" then read the socket and then send a reply, then readReply() is blocking, doing nothing but consuming time until the reply shows up.  The wait is a function of the duration of the quantum slice on both sides and how busy the cpu is doing other processes.

Comment: 800 messages per second (in reality 1600, as you're bidirectional) is about the maximum you can get, if your ping times are at about 1 ms. Using UDP won't help you, since the time the packets take traveling up and down the TCP/UDP/IP stack is MUCH longer than the time the spend on the network. If you want improved performance, implement some sliding window protocol: sender sends up to 20 messages before expecting the first reply.

Comment: @jimmcnamara 'The wait is a function of the duration of the quantum slice on both sides' only if both sides are overloaded, ie. have more ready threads than cores.  The OP horrible performance is 99.99% due to network latency and, quite possibly, nagle algorithm.

Comment: Can you pipeline your requests?  Does the client have to wait for the reply to request 1 from the server before sending request 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is latency: the time it takes for a network frame/package to reach the destination.

For instance, 1 ms latency limits the speed to at most 1000 frames/second. Latency of 2 ms can handle 500 fps, 10 ms gives 100 fps etc..

1. In this case, managing 1600 fps (800*2) is expected when latency is 0.5 ms.
2. *I think* this is because you manage to send more data per frame. It will fill up the TCP buffer in the client after a while though.
3. Batch (pipeline) the messages if possible. Send 10 messages from the client in a batch and then wait for the server to reply. The server should send all 10 replies in a single chunk as well. This should make the speed 10x faster in theory.